# How to minimize NavigationView / NavigationDrawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

I'm trying to minimize or collapse the `NavigationView` / `NavigationDrawer` when my app is running on tablets.

The result I want is the one used by **GMail** app, see screenshot below (you can see the desired layout collapsed on the left).

[image]

Does exists any method or a pattern to follow to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading carefully [this official NavigationDrawer guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#navigation-drawer-behavior), I found that my question used wrong *keywords* : it is called **mini navigation drawer** (that's why I edited my question first).

So I was able to find an answer:

1. Use [third party library](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer), which is proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32913462/2013835) (yes, my question is a duplicate!);
2. Develop your own solution, by following [this sample](https://github.com/nganthony/MiniNavigationDrawer); be aware that you have to add some fancy animation and other decoration in order to respect Material design guidelines.

Any way, the trick is to simply add a margin left to the detail view (`FrameLayout` in this case), like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--Master fragment-->
    <fragment
        android:name=".MainFragment"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_master">
    </fragment>

    <!--Detail layout -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="1000dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="56dp">
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>
```